# How is the structure of spectrum in cap-sets with no strong increments unrealistic if density is too large?

Tags: fourier-analysis, additive-combinatorics

I am reading [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5851) excellent paper by Bateman and Katz on improved bounds on the cap set problem.

Let A be a set in $\mathbb{F}_3^n$ containing no 3-term arithmetic progression and let $A(x)$ denote the characteristic function of $A$. Let $\alpha := E_{x \in \mathbb{F}_3^n}[A(x)] = n^{-1-\varepsilon}$. In the paper they call such a set $A$ a cap-set with no strong increments if for every subspace $H$ of codimension $d \le n/2$, 
     $$ E_{x}[A(x) | x \in H] \le \alpha + C \alpha \frac{d}{n}, $$
for an absolute constant $C$.

For a constant $c < 1$, let $\Delta := \{ \gamma \neq 1 | |\hat{A}(\gamma)| \ge c\alpha^2\}$ be the large spectrum of $A(x)$. Since $A$ is a cap-set, from Plancheral and the fact that density of $A$ on every codimension 1 subspace is at most $\alpha + C\alpha/n$, it can be shown that $n^3 \le |\Delta| \le n^{3+3\varepsilon}$.

The crux of the paper is a theorem about the structure of this spectrum. Essentially Bateman and Katz show that there is a $n^{\delta}$-dimensional subspace $H$ and a random set $\Lambda$ of size approximately $n^{2-\delta}$ such that $(H+\lambda) \cap \Delta$ is disjoint for each $\lambda \in \Lambda$ and has size at least $n^{1-\delta}$ where $\delta$ is some function of $\varepsilon$. The set $\Lambda$ is random in the sense that for any subspace $W$ of dimension $d$, $|W \cap \Lambda| \le dn^{\delta}$.

Afterwards, in Section 8, the paper uses this to derive a contradiction if $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small and even though I could follow the details in this section of the paper, I don't have much intuition as to why a statement such as above would leave to a contradiction. Is there some heuristic argument which might not be precisely correct but allows one to see why such a statement might be useful here?

Thank you!